# Do PyImport_ImportModule and import statement load into different namespace?

Tags: c++, python, import, python-c-api, python-embedding

Here is canonical example of a program [extending embedded Python 3.x](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.1/extending/embedding.html) in C/C++:

```
#include <Python.h>
//// Definition of 'emb' Python module ////////////////////
static PyObject* emb_foo(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    char const* n = "I am foo";
    return Py_BuildValue("s", n);
}
static PyMethodDef EmbMethods[] = {
    {"foo", emb_foo, METH_VARARGS, "Returns foo"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};
static PyModuleDef EmbModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "emb", NULL, -1, EmbMethods,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
};
static PyObject* PyInit_emb(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&EmbModule);
}
//// Embedded Python with 'emb' loaded ////////////////////
int main()
{
    PyImport_AppendInittab("emb", &PyInit_emb);
    Py_Initialize();

    PyRun_SimpleString("import emb\n");       // (1)
    //PyImport_ImportModule("emb");           // (2)

    PyRun_SimpleString("print(emb.foo())\n"); // (3)

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I add the `emb` module to built-ins of the embedded interpreter.
I'd also like to import it automatically, so users don't have to issue `import emb` statement in their scripts supplied to my embedded interpreter.
I'm trying two ways of importing, in lines **(1)** and **(2)**.

The **(1)** works and the `emb` module can be found without explicit import in the simple test in line **(3)**. However, if I comment out the line **(1)** and uncomment the line **(2)** to import with C API of Python 3 call, then the line **(3)** produces error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'emb' is not defined
```

I'd like to understand what is the difference here between the two manners of importing.
Do they import module into different [namespaces / scopes](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects) ?

The Python 3 documentation led me along this path:

1. [PyImport_ImportModule](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.1/c-api/import.html?highlight=pyimport_appendinittab#PyImport_ImportModule) is best described by referring to the built-in Python function `__import__()`
2. [`__import__()`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.1/library/functions.html#__import__) function is invoked by the import statement.

Perhaps I made a mistake assuming `PyImport_ImportModule` is one-to-one equivalent and I should be using [PyImport_ImportModuleEx](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.1/c-api/import.html?highlight=pyimport_appendinittab#PyImport_ImportModuleEx) with correct (which exactly?) globals and locals, so my 'emb' lands in global namespace of my embedded interpreter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`__import__` doesn't put the module in any namespace at all, but returns it instead. 
`import` calls `__import__`, plus it stores the result in a variable.
The [docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.1/library/functions.html#__import__) say that `import spam` does something similar to:

```
spam = __import__('spam', globals(), locals(), [], 0)
```

---

To get the same effect in the C API, you need to assign to the `emb` global. In other words, set the `emb` attribute on the `__main__` module.

```
PyObject* emb_module = PyImport_ImportModule("emb");
PyObject* main_module = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyObject_SetAttrString(main_module, "emb", emb_module);
Py_XDECREF(emb_module);
/* (main_module is a borrowed reference) */
```

Comment: +1 Works! I see where was my misunderstanding. Re untested code, just "emb" needs to be wrapped with PyUnicode_FromString("emb"). I've also noticed there is shortcut to get __main__: PyObject* main_module = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");

Comment: Edited, thanks. I used `PyObject_SetAttrString` rather than `PyUnicode_FromString` (shorter, less worrying about managing references).

Comment: I think the return value from PyImport_AddModule is a borrowed reference, so you shouldn't be decref'ing it.